# Cause of jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound even when using just jinja2

Tags: jinja2

The cause of the problem is obvious after the fact, but I'd like to share the not-too-obvious cause here.

When running code such as

```
import jinja2

templateLoader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(searchpath=".")
templateEnv = jinja2.Environment(loader=templateLoader,
                                 trim_blocks=True,
                                 lstrip_blocks=True)

htmlTemplateFile = 'file.jinja.html'
htmlTemplate = templateEnv.get_template(htmlTemplateFile)
```

if you get this problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
  File "file.py", line xyz, in some_func
    htmlTemplate = templateEnv.get_template(htmlTemplateFile)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 812, in get_template
    return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 774, in _load_template
    cache_key = self.loader.get_source(self, name)[1]
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 187, in get_source
    raise TemplateNotFound(template)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: file.jinja.html
```

you may find the discussions online point that this issue must have something to do with the interaction of jinja2 with [flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10792755/troubleshoot-templatenotfound-error-from-flask-under-gunicorn), with [GAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025321/problems-with-jinja2-templatenotfound-index-html), with [Pyramid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19174463/template-not-found-deploying-pyramid-on-webfaction), or with [SQL](http://www.iredmail.org/forum/topic9302-iredadminpro-support-internal-server-error-bug-class-jinja2exceptionstemplatenotfound.html), and it may indeed be that your templates are not in a "template" folder, but this problem can arise from the interaction of `jinja2` and the `os` module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit is changing the current directory by, for instance,

```
import os
os.chdir(someDir)
```

If `templateEnv.get_template(...)` is called past this point, jinja2 will look for the templates in the "current" dir, even if that has changed.

Since module `os` provides `os.chdir` but not `os.pushdir`/`os.popdir`, one has to either simulate the latter pair or avoid chdir altogether.